# Get background location updates (app in background / iPhone locked) with 'whileInUse' Location authorisation

Tags: ios, swift, background, core-location, background-position

I have a navigation app (iOS 9.3) that can also run in the background (voice guidance and coordinate and speed logging)

So far this only works when users accept the 'always' Location Access. When users change location access to 'While Using' the blue bar appears when back grounded (which is what I want, or at least don't mind) but Location updates stop after about 5 minutes of being backgrounded.

I noticed that Google Maps can do this even when location access is set to 'whileInUse' (blue bar 'Google Maps is using your location' appears when backgrounded) and was wondering exactly how they do it.

Could find some similar questions here on SO, but none that really could answer this.

I'm guessing that it has something to do with enabling 'Background App Refresh' for my app, but not sure... and if that's the solution how exactly would I go about that?

Comment: Location isn't the only background mode Google uses. The navigation also speaks out the directions using the speakers/audio. I assume that is what keeps the app functioning in the background and allowing the location to keep working. Don't think just of the location, if it isn't audio, think of what else they may be using to keep the app running in the background which also lets them keep getting location.

Comment: Yeah. My app also speaks nav instructions. So that's not sufficient to keep the app 'alive'. I think it's the background app refresh, but not sure how I'd have to implement it. (And... Might be against the guidelines to use a background mode not for its own purpose but to enable other background activities?)